# C++11 alias templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I ran to some problems with c++11 alias templates. As you can see below, I want to create an alias to A::B from class C. Before instantiation is made the compiler (gcc 6.1) cannot assert that V has a member type B, therefore giving the error:

```
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token  
template<typename ValueT> using B = typename V::B<ValueT>;
```

Does not his go against the usual way templates are dealt with in C++, that is assuming that the template type provides all necessary functionalities until proven otherwise by an instantiation?

```
template<typename T> class A{
    T a;
public:
    template <typename ValueT> class B {
        ValueT b;
    };
};

template <typename V = A<int>> class C {
public:
    template<typename ValueT> using B = typename V::B<ValueT>;
};
```

Comment: `template<typename ValueT> using B = typename V::template B<ValueT>;`

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see the duplicate question. I can't believe that after all those long years of C/C++ programming I can still get fooled by the syntax. Also, compilers' messages when it comes to templates are useless at best, misleading in the worst case.

Comment: As a side note, clang gives much better explanation of the problem: "error: use 'template' keyword to treat 'B' as a dependent template name"